# Kendo UI Combobox - Loading huge data

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

We have implemented Kendo Combobox which will load about 20 thousand records with customized template. But its taking large amount of time. Is there any way to improve performance while loading data for first time?

Comment: Try [virtualization](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/virtualization)

Comment: You want to add 20 thousand items into a combobox? Maybe you should think more about your design rather than trying to speed it up. There is no way I want to look through 20,000 options to find the one that I want. If you added a search-while-you-type feature it would cut down the options greatly and be much easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you should not try to optimize the loading of a huge amount of data.
Instead you should filter the data you retrieve on the server side by using server filtering feature of either the [Kendo Combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/serverfiltering) or the [Kendo Autocomplete](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/autocomplete/serverfiltering) control.

Taking code sample for the pages I linked, I highlighted the important parts below:

```
$("#products").kendoComboBox({
            placeholder: "Select product",
            dataTextField: "ProductName",
            dataValueField: "ProductID",
            filter: "contains",
            autoBind: false, //this is important
            minLength: 3,
            dataSource: {
                type: "odata",
                serverFiltering: true, //this is important
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Northwind.svc/Products",
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```